# Cesium: are there any easy hacks to load non-square tile images on Cesium?

Tags: tiles, cesium

The map tile images I created have non-square tiles in the maps edge. If the image format is png, I can put transparent pixels to make images square, but unfortunately, my image format is jpg, so I can't add transparent pixels to tiles.

If Cesium loads non-square tile images, it expands the tile image fit to be square, and this looks so bad.  Remodelling ImageryProvider.js to add transparent pixels to the tile on-the-fly is the possible solution, and actually I did this on OpenLayers 3, but it takes too much effort.

Are there any good hacks to load non-square tiles on Cesium, with no or light effort?

Comment: What counts as too much (or heavy) effort? Is it too much effort for you, or is it causing problems to your PC?  What counts as a good hack (as opposed a standard or bad hack)?

Comment: Do you really mean "without needing to modify Cesium"? Can you just add white or black fill to your JPEG tiles, or bulk convert everything to PNG?

Comment: nmtoken - I mean "without or less modifying Cesium". I once modified OpenLayers3, but it takes too much time to understand OL3 inside and also take too much effort to keep delta each time OL3's update.  
BradHards - jpeg tiles overlay to other map, so black/white background is not good, and PNG is 10 times larger size than for JPG, for my image. It is something like photo.

Comment: Possible solution I found by myself is, only edge tiles convert to PNG. identifying edge tile is easy, so if I call PNG instead of JPG for edge tiles, this may work.
But if there are another way to solve this, I want to know...